# I really like you answer, or do I?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Why should one be able to up vote an answer they have selected?

Should the selection of an answer be enough, Why the extra +10?

Is this a way of saying I "REALLY" like you answer?

Was that the intention?

Or should one's answer selection reverse the upvote?

Comment: Upvote = 10 pts; Accept = 15.  Where do you get +2?  (not my dnvote)

Comment: Why would upvotes and acceptance be mutually exclusive? You've suggested a change to the current behaviour without *any* reason why you think that change would be an improvement or why you think the current system isn't working correctly.

Answer (score 17):

All the Stack Overflow dark sides in one question.

Too many people do believe that this site is to express their feelings, good intentions, likes, sermons, emotions, hurted senses, political views. Will they ever learn it is not?
This site is not for "likes". It. Is. For. Answering. Questions.
Accept doesn't mean like. It means "correct".

Don't count points in someone's pocket. It sounds like jealousy. Don't be obsessed with reputation points at all, either yours or someone's else. That's not the thing to care of.

Comment: I would go so far as to say that "accepted" doesn't even mean "correct", just "worked for me".

Comment: @John It *should* be correct.

Comment: @bjb568 correct and works are not always the same thing.  There are plenty of post asking to unpin accepted answers from the top of the answer as they contain bad/unsafe practices/code in them.

Comment: @NathanOliver Exactly my point. They are different things, and accepted should mean correct.

Comment: @bjb568 The accepted answer really doesn't mean anything except that the OP liked/used it.  You cannot derive anything else about the quality or usability of the answer based on it.  Votes on the other hand do signal quality on the answer.  From the help file: *Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly. It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for him or her personally*

Comment: @NathanOliver That's the perfect argument for removing the accept vote, which already has community consensus among SE veterans on MSE chat. The accept vote gives the loudest voice to the person who knows the least about the topic: the poor bloke who was so lost that he shamefully *asked a question on Stack Overflow*.

Comment: @bjb568 Magnificently worded. This statement have to be cast in granite!